# Change Feed Processor - Multiple consumers acquiring leases on all the partitonIds

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have 2 instances of a worker role listening to the same collection in CosmosDb using the Change Feed Processor. I am receiving duplicate data because both the consumers have acquired leases on all the partitions and the same data is being streamed twice.

I have used the LeasePrefix property of the ChangeFeedHostOptions and set it to the instance name (`RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id`)

Here is an example from lease collection:

```
Consumer1
{
    "id": "WorkerRole1_IN_1xyz.documents.azure.com_v0QfAA==_v0QfAKJwMgA=..0",
    "_etag": "\"0000c601-0000-0000-0000-5acf0fca0000\"",
    "state": 2,
    "PartitionId": "0",
    "Owner": "WorkerRole1_IN_1",
    "ContinuationToken": "\"115725\"",
    "SequenceNumber": 1,
    "_rid": "DiADAKjOkAMDAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/DiADAA==/colls/DiADAKjOkAM=/docs/DiADAKjOkAMDAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1523519434
}

Consumer2:
{
    "id": "WorkerRole1_IN_0xyz.documents.azure.com_v0QfAA==_v0QfAKJwMgA=..4",
    "_etag": "\"00007e01-0000-0000-0000-5acf0fcc0000\"",
    "state": 2,
    "PartitionId": "0",
    "Owner": "WorkerRole1_IN_0",
    "ContinuationToken": "\"115725\"",
    "SequenceNumber": 1,
    "_rid": "DiADAPNPPAMDAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/DiADAA==/colls/DiADAPNPPAM=/docs/DiADAPNPPAMDAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1523519436
}
```

Here are the feed options I have used:

```
ChangeFeedOptions feedOptions = new ChangeFeedOptions
{
    StartFromBeginning = true,
    MaxItemCount = 10000,
    StartTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7)
};

ChangeFeedHostOptions feedHostOptions = new ChangeFeedHostOptions
{
    LeasePrefix = Configs.hostName,
    FeedPollDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
};
```

Can someone tell me if I am missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are receiving duplicates is because you are using the LeasePrefix. The LeasePrefix states:

> This can be used to support multiple ChangeFeedEventHost instances pointing at the same feed while using the same auxiliary collection.

The goal of that property is to actually do that, share the same lease collection with multiple independent Hosts.

To solve your issue, just remove the LeasePrefix assignment or use the same Prefix for both.

Comment: Thanks, for your quick response. Really appreciate it!. I did remove the lease prefix and also changed the ChangeFeedEventHost creation to use a common host name across both the consumers. I still end up getting duplicates :(

Comment: Try removing all documents in your "leases" collection and starting the hosts. The hosts don't need the same name. After both hosts start, check the "leases" collection.

Comment: I did try that. When the hosts have different names they acquire leases on different partitions (no overlap).  
For ex:    
"PartitionId": "1",
"Owner": "WorkerRole1_IN_1",

"PartitionId": "2",
"Owner": "WorkerRole1_IN_0",

But I still end up getting duplicates, each document is being processed by both the consumers.
Is there something to do with specifying the PartitionKeyRangeId ?

Comment: Are you specifying the PartitionKeyRangeId in the ChangeFeedOptions? It doesn't show that in your code sample.